# How to play youtube video inside a floating popup window in android

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, popup

I can create a floating popup window using standout library https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut . As I understand this library creates a service which creates a popup window.

Youtube API for Android provides YouTubePlayerView, which can be only used with YoutubeBaseActivity, and which I cannot use because the floating popup window belongs to a service.

Youtube API also provides YoutubePlayerFragment, which also cannot be used because services cannot work with fragments.

There is also WebView, which can be used here, which is not as nice as Youtube API for Android, but better than nothing. It almost works for me. The WebView is displayed inside a floating popup window, and the video is being played, but the video is just black.

Here is WebView code

```
    private static final String FRAME_VIDEO = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"320\" height=\"280\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/_oEA18Y8gM0\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></body></html>";


    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadData(FRAME_VIDEO, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Maybe one of these options is possible:

1. Somehow use YoutubePlayerView without YouTubeBaseActivity
2. Use fragments without activity
3. Fix the WebView code
4. Maybe there is some other way to play youtube videos inside a floating popup window

Comment: Could you provide some more details, why the fragment does not work? I just took a quick look in the lib and it seems you can add a layout with a Fragment to the StandOutWindow.

Comment: If I place a layout with YouTube fragment in it I will need to access the fragment in the java code. To get a fragment from a layout I need a FragmentManager. But my class which creates the floating window has to inherit from StandOutWindow which inherits from Service. And a FragmentManager can be used only within the classes which inherit from Activity

Comment: WebView works fine on Android 5. Because of some reason webview youtube does not work on Kitkat. Also I had another idea. If i make a static YouTubePlayerView, initialize it inside YouTubeBaseActivity and then atach this view to the StandOutWindow. It worked, but the stopped the moment I closed the MainActivity. Also I tried to create invisible activity, but this way user cannot press anything behind the activity.

Comment: Yeah pretty hard to find a nice solution here i guess. As you might know,Kitkat has a lower Webview Version with some limitations, which surely cause your problems. The bad news are, that the WebView does not get any updates on Kitkat :/

Comment: I see that there is next to none information on how to implement a floating player. I would think that this is not to be done on Android. But there are a lot of apps which feature a floating YouTube player, and they work much better than my WebView try. It's weird that something is getting popular and is that difficult to implement.

Comment: But they seem to have similar problems. (the ones I found). Youtube Videos only available on API 5.0+ Devices. Have you tried to set hardware acceleration on API 5.0 Devices? setLayerType(...) This might give you a performance boost. Sry that I can't help more.